# Informal first person plural object

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-personnels

In spoken French, "on" replaces *nous* as a subject pronoun. I don't understand how to say something like

Do you want us to come?

or

You owe us money.

or

Tell us!

Do French speakers use *nous* here, even in highly informal conversation?

Comment: The assumption that using _on_ for _nous_ is to be kept for informal situations implies that the use of _nous_ implies a formal one is false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“*On*” can only replace “*nous*” when it is a subject pronoun. In the first example, the corresponding French sentence has “*nous*”/“*on*” as a subject of the verb *come*, so “*on*” can be used.

> Do you want us to come

From more formal to less formal.

- Veux-tu/voulez-vous que nous venions ?
- Veux-tu que l’on vienne ?
- Veux-tu qu’on vienne ?
- Tu veux qu’on vienne ?

In the two other, “us” is not subject, thus using “*on*” is impossible.

> You owe us money.

- Tu nous dois de l’argent.

> Tell us!

- Raconte-nous !
- Dis-nous !

Comment: Thanks. Similarly, even in informal French, do you say notre ? E.g. "On a oublié notre argent "

Comment: Yes, “*On a ou oublié notre argent*”.

Comment: For the translation of "Tell us", just "Raconte." and "Dis." are very common.

Comment: [tell us](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hAm2EW-Iv8)

Comment: Keep in mind that _on_ was originally used for an undefined subject. _À Saint-Meumeu, **on** va à la messe tous les dimanches, puis **on** mange de la tourtière pour dîner._ Here, _on_ does not imply the one who's talking and his friends, but rather the citizens of Saint-Meumeu, who have a global habit of going to church every Sunday, then having meat pie for lunch. Nowadays, _on_ has been used much more as a replacement for _nous_ in common language usage.

Answer (score 0):

Basically just remember that “on” is the equivalent of “one” (as in `on doit etre gentil/one should be kind`) and “nous” corresponds to “we” (nous chantons/we sing) or “us” (dis-nous/tell us) or rarely ours (as in `chez nous`).

Comment: Whoever has downvoted should explain the reasons for doing so

Comment: I'm, not the one who downvoted you. It probably was related to the fact that what you describe about _on_ <-> _one_ does not reflect the most common use of _on_ in the "langage familier", which is the equivalent for nous. _On_ was used as an impersonal pronoun, nowadays, it's very personal.

Comment: I think these two statements are equivalent in meaning: One should be kind or we should be kind. So I am not sure whether I understand your comment. I suppose you are confusing the meaning of “one” in English. Please note that I do not refer to it in the sense of number one.

Comment: I'm aware you're not referring to the the number one :) And yes, _One should be kind_ and _We should be kind_ may have an equivalent meaning when _we_ is interpreted a "people", at large. If _we_ is used in the context where it designate a precise group of person, it does not have the exact same meaning. Here, _we_ is a bit like _on_: Bob says: "Les gars, on mange d'la pizza ce midi?" here _on_ designates precisely Bob and is friends, while in "Au Québec, on aime Céline Dion.", _on_ designates population from Québec, at large. (Do we lunch with pizza? v.s. In Québec we/one like/s Celine Dion.)

Comment: I see what you mean. But if you say "Au Québec, on aime Céline Dion", you are likely to be from Quebec, no?

Comment: I am. Is this much different from the other parts of the french world? I know a couple of French (from France) who use _on_ for _nous_ most of the time. You seem to have had different experiences.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12604/discussion-between-alexandre-vaillancourt-and-abhimanyu-arora)

Comment: A la difference d'"*on*" en francais, "*one*" en anglais peut servir d'***objet*** -- pas seulement de sujet. (Et oui, en anglais c'est moins courant et plus formel.) Voir [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(pronoun)).

Comment: @Drew: Je ne comprends pas. Pouvez vous me expliquer en Anglais, svp?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: Il me semble qu'en francais on ne peut pas utiliser "on" comme objet (direct ou indirect). En anglais, on peut. Voir les [exemples wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(pronoun)) pour "verbal object", "prepositional object", "dative", et "genitive". Voici l'exemple pour "verbal object", par ex. : ***Drunkenness makes one unreliable.*** Le sujet de la phrase est "drunkenness"; l'objet est "one".

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: Sorry, you asked for English. In French, you cannot use "on" as the object (direct or indirect) of a sentence. You can only use it as the subject.  In English, you can use "one" as either subject or object. See the [wikipedia examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(pronoun)) for "One (pronoun)".

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: In case it's not clear, I agree with your answer, as far as it goes.  I only added that "on" is not exactly equivalent to "one", since the former cannot be used as the object. The other difference I see is usage: "on" is common in French; "one" is less common in English, and "one" often has a connotation of being a bit formal or forced.

Comment: @Drew:Thanks for the clarification, at least there's one person who understands :-)

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: Nope, sorry; I'm no expert. Just someone who speaks English and (less well) French.

Comment: @Drew: Editted :-)